# The function $f$ is continuous at $\left[ a,b\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The function $f$ is continuous at $\left[ a,b\right]$.How to show this equations? If $f\left( x\right) =0$ for $\forall x\in Q\cap \left[ a,b\right]$ $\Rightarrow$ $f\left( x\right) =0$ for $x\in \left[ a,b\right]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of arguing is as follows. Since $f$ is continuous and $\{0\}$ is closed, then the set
$$
E = f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{x : f(x) = 0\}
$$
is also closed. Since $\mathbb{Q}\subset E$, we also have $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\subset E$ where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$. But finally as $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$, $E = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to note that the rational are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. So $\forall x \in [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}^{c}$ $\exists \{x_n \} \subset [a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_n \to x$. By the continuity of f we know that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. We have that $f(x_n)=0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking to prove that if $f$ is continous and equal to  $0$ for every rational in $[a, b]$, then $f$ is equal to $0$ for every number in $[a, b]$.

Suppose there was some number $y \in [a, b]$ such that $f(y) \not = 0$. Because $f$ is continous, for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $f(y)$ whenever  $x$ is within $\delta$ of $y$.

But think about what happens if we pick $\epsilon$ to be less than the absolute value of $f(y)$. There must exist some $\delta$ such that all the values of $f$ must be within $\epsilon$ of $f(y)$. But no matter how small of a $\delta$ you pick, you will always find a rational number within $\delta$ of $y$, and the image of this rational number will not be within $\epsilon$ of $f(y)$.

[image]